# When should I close the webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I use Scrapy and Selenium for scraping.

when i run my spider, with `htop` i see the instance of my webdriver.

I would like to know when should I close the webdriver in my code ?

```
def parse():
    # I have all links in my array_links
    for link in self.array_links:
        self.driver.get(link)

        # Here i Parse the products
        item = MyTestItem()
        item['test1'] = "test"
        yield item
```

I add this in my code

```
def __del__(self):
    self.driver.quit()
```

for the end of the script, but I don't know should I `close` webdriver after having taken each link?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is. Where do you open it?

If your webdriver is in the context of spider then ideally you'd want to open it when spider opens and close it when spider closes.

You can do that by connectin `open_spider` and `close_spider` signals:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy import Spider


class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "spideroo"

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super().from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return spider

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        self.driver = selenium.WebDriver()  # or what's your driver's class is.

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.driver.close()
```

Comment: Yes i open it at the beginning, just after name = "spideroo", so i think that what i do is correct too. thanks for your answer